# React Navigation throw error

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have a router.js file where all my routes and screens are defined and SearchFilter and a Home component where everything get together to render in one component including SearchFilter. when i pass onPress prop to one of SearchFilter component to navigate to another screen i get an error: 
"undefined is not an object . _this.props.navigation.native -> onPress(SearchFilter)". When i only alert something then it works. please see the code. Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks

//SearchFilter

```
class SearchFilter extends React.Component{

    render(){
        return (
            <View style={styles.main}>
                <View style={styles.wrapper}>

                    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.buttonShape} 

                     onPress={ // Here lies the error*************

                       () => this.props.navigation.navigate('Details')}

                     >

                        <Text style={styles.text}>Super-Market</Text>
                        <Image source={require('./icons/supermarket.png')} />
                    </TouchableOpacity>

                </View>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

// Router

```
export const ScreenSwitch = StackNavigator({
    Home:{
        screen: Home,
        navigationOptions:{
            title: 'Home'
        }
    },
    SearchFilter: {
        screen: SearchFilter,
        navigationOptions: {
            title: 'SearchFilter'
        }
    },
    Details: {
        screen: MemberDetails,
        navigationOptions: {
            title: 'MemberDetails'
        }
    },

}
```

//Home

```
class Home extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return(
            <View style = {styles.main}>
                <Header/>
                <SearchFilter/>

                <ScrollView contentContainerStyle = {styles.scroll}>
                    <Card />
                </ScrollView>

            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Why `SearchFilter` became part of the navigator, are you going to navigate to `SearchFilter` from other screens? I can see that you have used `SearchFilter` as a component in your `Home` component.

Comment: i want to have SeachFilter as a button on Home screen which should navigate to Details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that `SearchFilter` is not part of `navigator`, rather its a component but you want to use `navigation` object within this component. `react-navigation` offer `withNavigation` function to wrap your HOC component. Here is the [link](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/with-navigation.html#docsNav)

So the changes in you code will be

```
class SearchFilter extends React.Component {
  ...
}
export default withNavigation(SearchFilter);
```

As you can see above that, I have wrapped it into `withNavigation`, inside the component you can access the `navigation` object using `this.props.navigation.*`.

Also, you do not need SearchFilter in stack navigator.

Hope this will help.